# Remove a char from a String

Tags: c#, .net, string

I'm looking for a method which can remove a character of a string.
for example I have " 3*X^4" and I want to remove characters '*' & '^' then the string would be like this "3X4" .

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and [Check List](http://tinyurl.com/so-list)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe:

```
string s = Regex.Replace(input, "[*^]", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var s = "3*X^4";
var simplified = s.Replace("*", "").Replace("^", "");
// simplified is now "3X4"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..it will remove all special character from string

```
public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in str) 
    {
       if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') 
       || c ==  '.' || c == '_')
       {
          sb.Append(c);
       }
    }
 return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  [String.Replace(Old String, New String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

```
string S = "3*X^4";
string str = S.Replace("*","").Replace("^","");
```

Comment: That's what @deerchao suggested

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be extracting the unwanted characters manually - this might be slightly more performant than repeatedly calling `string.Replace` especially for larger numbers of unwanted characters:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
foreach (char ch in input) {
    switch (ch) {
        case '*':
        case '^':
            break;
        default:
            result.Append(ch);
            break;
    }
}
string s = result.ToString();
```

Or maybe *extracting* is the wrong word: Rather, you copy all characters except for those that you don't want.